# polylang: rtl menu items order as in English

Tags: wordpress

I'm using polylang to use Arabic it works fine except the menu navigation.Normally I should get the menu order in Arabic from right to left but what I got is an arabic menu order as in English from left.
so what i need is a menu align right (already satisfied) and the order of the menu items to be from right to left (my problem)

Comment: So the site itself does work as rtl, but text in menu isn't? Can you provide the URL?

Comment: yes the site works as rtl, text on the menu as well but the problem is with the order of items . about url I m working on local

Comment: Do you mean if first menu item in English is "Home", it is on the corner left as a first item, when in arabic, you need that "Home" to be as the first item on the right?

Comment: exactly is what i need

Comment: Added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to solve it by setting up appropriate properties in the `<li>` menu elements.

To make sure that it only gets applied with RTL language, check the web page source code if it has some `.rtl` or 'arabic' related class and then use that for the CSS specificity.

```
.rtl main-menu li {
    text-align:right;
}
```